# WCF Operation contract availability

Tags: wcf

This question was asked at interview.
Say I have a contract.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
  [OperationContract]
  void methodForClientA();

   [OperationContract]
   void  AnothermethodForClientA();

   [OperationContract]
   void methodForClientB();

  [OperationContract]
  void  AnothermethodForClientB();
}
```

When a clientA access the contract it should only  see the operation contracts

```
void methodForClientA(),void  AnothermethodForClientA().
```

**Is it possible in WCF ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot keep client A and client B from seeing each other's methods, because they're all defined in the same contract.

You can, however, keep Client A and Client B from *calling* each other's methods, using WCF's security mechanisms.

Alternatively, you could have two separate services, each unique to the client.

**Edit**

The more I think about it, the more I would prefer the separate services options for such a scenario. If you have methods *specific* to each client, you really have separate services anyway, each specific to the particular client.